# How can I make two activity like android in IOS(React Native)?

Tags: ios, react-native

I want to make a app that will have two activity with different app launching icon in IOS(React Native).

I have made this in Android. The code is given bellow.

```
      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>

      <activity
        android:name=".NotifierActivity"
        android:label="SOS"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_sos"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_sos_round"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
```

I am beginner. So, I need your help badly.

Answer (score 0):

> An example for mainfest, Let me know if you are seeking for more help.
>   You need to add this in app/AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.xxx">

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
        <application
            android:name=".MainApplication"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:allowBackup="false"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:largeHeap="true"
            android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
            >
        <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>

      <activity
        android:name=".NotifierActivity"
        android:label="SOS"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_sos"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_sos_round"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: I am searching for IOS solution like your android one. If you have IOS solution please share with me

Comment: check launchOptions options inside AppDelegate.m, And icon you can add in ios/projectname/Image.xcassets. You should use xcode to do this.

Comment: I am using xcode. If you have sample for IOS provide me